# Scala higher-kinded type and covariant

Tags: scala, covariance, higher-kinded-types

I'm trying to abstract over some library API that can return any of type `A`, `Option[A]` or `Seq[A]`.

So far, I have something like this:

```
  type Const[T] = T

  sealed abstract class Request[F[_], A]

  case class GetOne(id: Int) extends Request[Const, Int]
  case class GetMany() extends Request[Seq, String]
```

And then when I use it:

```
def get[F[_], A](request: Request[F, A]): F[A] = request match {
  case GetOne(id) => client.getOne[F[A]](id)
  case GetMany() => client.getMany[A]() // error: Seq[A] does not conform to F[A]
}
```

I understand why this wouldn't work in that `F[_]` is not subclass of `covariant` `Seq[_]` or something like that. But I'm not sure how I can work around while still being able to use `Const[A]`. Am I hopeless? Please help.

Comment: Where does the type `FetchRequest` come from, what is its type signature?

Comment: @isi Oops. That was a typo. It's `Request`.

Comment: So `client.getMany[A]()` returns a `Seq[A]` and is your library call, right?

Comment: @isi That's correct.

Comment: I'm still a novice with higher kinded types myself, but I think your approach is targeting a too common type family. Allowing your function `get` receiving any `F[_]` makes me ask myself what would your call mean if `F` would be a `List` or something less obvious like a `Future`. I think using a higher kinded type is too abstract in this case. The function would not have any chance to guarantee that only valid types of `F` are given, thus resulting in a `MatchError` and breaking at runtime or if available providing a valid default in that case. But I suspect this would be a useful default ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For such type of polymorphism you could use typeclass concept
Considering

```
trait Client {
  def getOne[X]: X
  def getMany[X]: Seq[X]
}

type Const[T] = T

sealed abstract class Request[F[_], A]

case class GetOne(id: Int) extends Request[Const, Int]
case class GetMany() extends Request[Seq, String]
```

We could define such typeclass:

```
trait HandleRequest[R <: Request[F, A], F[_], A] {
  def apply(request: R, client: Client): F[A]
}
```

And instantiate it for desired cases:

```
implicit object handleGetOne extends HandleRequest[GetOne, Const, Int] {
  def apply(request: GetOne, client: Client): Int = client.getOne
}

implicit object handleGetMany extends HandleRequest[GetMany, Seq, String] {
  def apply(request: GetMany, client: Client): Seq[String] = client.getMany
}
```

Now you could define your general function as follows:

```
implicit class ClientOps(val client: Client) {
  def get[R <: Request[F, A], F[_], A](request: R)(implicit handle: HandleRequest[R, F, A]): F[A] =
    handle(request, client)
}
```

If you ever like to generalize your request types, for instance:

```
case class GetOne[X](id: Int) extends Request[Const, X]
case class GetMany[X]() extends Request[Seq, X]
```

You could redefine your instances as:

```
implicit def handleGetOne[X] = new HandleRequest[GetOne[X], Const, X] {
  def apply(request: GetOne[X], client: Client): X = client.getOne
}

implicit def handleGetMany[X] = new HandleRequest[GetMany[X], Seq, X] {
  def apply(request: GetMany[X], client: Client): Seq[X] = client.getMany
}
```

Comment: With "For such type of polymorphism" I think it is meant: When abstracting over a finite set of _N_ types. Using this definition allows to say: Find an abstraction `A` saying `Request` which wraps your _N_ types e.g. using inheritance and/or higher kinded types. Then restrict operations to use your abstraction `A` or any bounded type of it. With this definition one can then give something like a recipe to reuse the answer or the OP's question in a general context. And your answer provides already two solutions AFAIK.

Comment: Bravo! This is so smart. It works. Thank you so much! I admire your scala skillz :]

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to this after a few months, I've realized I could have used `path-dependent type` to achieve the same result while being more concise and without requiring typeclass pattern.

```
type Const[T] = T

sealed trait Request {
  type F[_]
  type A
  type FA = F[A]

  def query(client: Client): Future[FA]
}

case class GetOne(id: Int) extends Request {
  type F[x] = Const[x]
  type A = Int
  def query(client: Client): Future[Int] = client.getOne(id)
}

case class GetMany(id: Int) extends Request {
  type F[x] = Seq[x]
  type A = String
  def query(client: Client): Future[Seq[String]] = client.getMany(id)
}
```

And then we can call it without an explosion of type parameters:

```
def get[R <: Request](request: R): request.FA = request.query(client)
```